# React Native - Is Redux-Persist really necessary in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

As redux-persist is necessary in Web App (ReactJS) because if we refresh our webpage our redux store gets clear so thats why redux-persist is necessary in Web App (ReactJS). But is it really necessary in a React Native app ? because I tried to minimize the app (didn't closed it from recent apps) and when I opened the app again my redux store was not cleared at all. I even tried to use "RefreshControl" to refresh the app but still my redux store wasn't cleared at all. So I want to ask is redux-persist really necessary for React Native apps ?

Comment: minimizing doesn't clear out the store, kind of like minimizing your browser. redux persist in RN is useful when you want state to persist when the app is completely closed out